# Java 7 JDK auto update

Tags: java, java-7, auto-update

Is there a way to set Java 7 so it will update automatically? I using JDK Standard edition on windows 7, 64bit. Java 6 would check for updates automatically and prompt you to install them. However, Java 7 doesn't appear to have any update mechanism. Even the "Update" tab in the Java Control Panel is gone.

Comment: This is the same thing as "auto updating", but you can push an update across a network: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/msi_install.xml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this might be the issue.  From the [Oracle Download Help pages](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_update.xml):

> Q: Why is the Update tab missing from the Java Control Panel?
>
> A: Java Auto Update is currently not available for 64-bit versions of Java. 64-bit versions of Java do not include the Update tab in the Java Control Panel.

See also:

- ["Java control panel does not show update tab on windows-7-x64"](https://superuser.com/questions/275700/java-control-panel-does-not-show-update-tab-on-windows-7-x64) on superuser.com.